# Move all files from listed directories one level up

Tags: bash, files, find, mv

I have a tree of directories, I need to remove some of them and move all files from these directories one level up.

I know how to do it step by step, but there are thousands of them, so I need to optimize the process.

I look for directories `find . -type d -name 'src'` and then I need to move all files from found directories one level up (`../`).

```
root
- one
-- two
--- src
- three
-- four
--- five
---- src
```

contents of first `src` should be moved to `two`, second `src` to `five`

How can I do it with one script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
find . -type d -name src -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"; for f in *; do mv -i "$f" .. ; done' find-sh {} \;
```

Note the `-i` flag to `mv`.  If it asks you for confirmation about overwriting something, you should say "no" unless you're expecting it.

Since you said you also want to remove the `src` directories afterward, use:

```
find . -type d -name src -exec sh -c 'cd "$1"; for f in *; do mv -i "$f" .. ; done' find-sh {} \; -exec rmdir {} \;
```

**Make a backup first.**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no nested `src` as its sub-directories in each level and the  `src` is the latest directory level, then below should do the job.

```
find . -path '*/src/*' -type f -execdir echo mv -t ../ {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way I know is to:

1. `cd` "where your directories are"
2. Now use `tar` to save them somewhere: `tar -cvf` "file name to save to such as /tmp/mysavfil.tar" "name of all the directories such as: foo bar and so on" so you get: `tar -cvf /tmp/mysavfil.tar foo bar`
3. Then do: `cd ..`
4. Then: `tar xvf /tmp/mysavfil.tar`
5. Optionally if you wish delete the no longer needed files as follows: `cd` "the original place where your files were"; `rm -rf foo bar`; `rm /tmp/mysavefiltar`
6. You are done

A much simpler way is to do:

- `mv foo bar ../.`